# javascript: How to get each record id on data-id from foreach?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html

I have a category list table which gets records from foreach. Every row has delete button and this button has data-id gets id from the row. I also have a function which gets data-id. But there is a problem, I always get first record id.

[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGMZY.jpg)

[Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NljOl.jpg)

```
Global.js: 

    function DeleteCategory() {
                var Id = $("#Cid").attr("data-id");
                alert(Id); 
            }
```

Index.cshtml:

```
  <tbody>
                                @foreach (var item in Model)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><span class="label label-success">@item.Id</span></td>
                                        <td>@item.CategoryName</td>
                                        <td>
                                            @if (item.IsActive)
                                            {
                                                <b  class="label label-success">Active</b>
                                            }
                                            else
                                            {
                                                    <b  class="label label-danger">Passive</b>
                                            }
                                        </td>
                                        <td>Server updates and maintenance</td>
                                        <td><a href="#">Admin</a></td>
                                        <td>
                                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="editId" onclick="" data-id="">Edit</button>
                                            @*@Html.ActionLink("Delete","Delete", new {id=item.Id },new { onclick = "return confirm('Do you want to delete this row?')"})*@
                                            <button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="Cid" onclick="DeleteCategory()" data-id="@item.Id">Delete</button>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>

                                }
```

Comment: do you want to get all id's or selected row id value?

Comment: `id` attribute __must__ be unique on a page, use classes.

Comment: selected row id but I always get first record's id for every delete button

Comment: Remove your `id` attributes in the loop. Use a class name (say `class="delete"`) instead and then `$('.delete').click(function() { var id = $(this).data('id'); ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`id` attribute of an element **must be unique** on page. This means that 2 or more elements with same id are not allowed. Only first element with this `id` will be considered as a real element. You can use classes instead.

But in your case it is easier to pass itemId directly to your `DeleteCategory` function:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-sm" id="Cid" onclick="DeleteCategory(@item.Id)">Delete</button>
```

And modify it as:

```
function DeleteCategory(Id) {
    alert(Id); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agreed with above comment, the html attribute id is the culprit id="Cid" On any html page all the id should be unique. when you write $("#Cid") its search in DOM tree and always return first element found with this id. You have to generate dynamic id based on item.Id or you can pass the values as parameter in DeleteCategory() function. Hope It'll help.